# Expo Image picker not working in Android but works in IOS

Tags: node.js, react-native, redux, expo, redux-toolkit

I am trying to give users of my React Native Expo based application the option to upload image via their gallery or camera shot. It is working in IOS but has refused to work in Android. I have read everything I can lay my hands on but I can't seem to get it to work. I am using both Android studio to test the app and a physical device connected to Expo android app.

When I call the API that handles image upload, it doesn't reach my server at all before throwing error. Here is the error:

```
 {"error": "TypeError: Network request failed", "status": "FETCH_ERROR"}
```

I am using Redux Query to make API requets. I also tried to use Axios and still got same error.
Here is how I used `formData` to handle the image data to the backend:
Note: imageInfo is coming from redux where I stored the data sent by `Expo Image picker`: Here is what the data looks like:

```
{"assetId": null, "base64": null, "duration": null, "exif": null, "height": 2499, "rotation": 
null, "type": "image", "uri":"file:///data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/cache/ExperienceData/%2540valvetech%252FchickenEat/
ImagePicker/aab1b518-2e22-463a-b85b-9e402ea62bbd.png", "width": 3332}




const handleUploadImage = async () => {

let uri = imageInfo?.uri
let filename = imageInfo?.uri.split("/")[11]
let type = mine.getType(filename)
let formData = new FormData();
formData.append("name", filename);
 formData.append('file', { uri: uri, name: filename, type: type });

  if(formData){
    console.log(formData, "formdata")
    //called the API endpoint here
    //const res = await axios.post(`${BASE_URL}/upload`, formData)
    await uploadImage(formData)
  }
 
 }
```

This is my base URL to which API requests are made:

```
const BASE_URL = "http://my-ip-address:5000/api/v1";
```

The backend uses `Node.js, Sequelize, MYSQL`

Like I said, every other API requests work and this image upload works in IOS without any issue. How can I get this to work in Android?

Comment: Did you solve your issue? If yes can you please give the solution?

Comment: Yea, do you still need help?

Comment: Yes please, I have not been able to solve it

Comment: check the answer I dropepd. That was how i solved it for andriod.

Answer (score 1):

You must use split. No use `photo.uri` --- use photo only

```
const createFormData = (noCase,photo, body = {}) => {
  const data = new FormData();
  const type = photo.split(".").pop();
  const name = photo.split("/").pop();
  data.append('case', noCase);
  data.append('imagen', {
    name: name,
    type: `image/${type}`,
    uri: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? photo.replace('file://', '') : photo,
  });

const handleUploadPhoto = () => {
  fetch(`${SERVER_URL}/cargar_fotos`, {
    method: 'POST',
    body: createFormData(1,photo),
  })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((response) => {
      console.log('response', response);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log('error', error);
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem for the andriod using this code:

```
I created a function that accepts the image handler from expo as props like this:

 export const createHandleImageUpload = (imageInfo) => {


  //This will fetch the infomation for andriod
  const fileURL = imageInfo?.uri?.split("/")[11]//get the name of the file using 
the file url, split the file by / and target the 11 index
const fileType = fileURL?.split(".")[1];//split the file url via . and target 
the file in index 1
const mineType = "image/" + fileType // add image with the file extension
const uri = imageInfo?.uri 


 let data
 if(Platform.OS == 'android'){
 const formData = new FormData();
 formData.append("name", fileURL);
 formData.append("file", {uri: uri,name: fileURL, type: mineType})
 data = formData
 }else{

 let formData = new FormData();
 formData.append("name", filename);
 formData.append('file', { uri: imageInfo?.uri, name: imageInfo?.uri, type: 
 imageInfo?.uri });

  data = formData
  }

  return data
 
  }
```